# Use AND OR in conjunction

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I usually use AND and OR together on formulas and they are not too difficult but I working on a document where I need to use a conditional AND and OR.

People will get a discount in either of two ways. I have four conditions:

```
Condition A "Cta Cte"
Condition B >23
Condition C "Cta Corriente"
Condition D >25
```

If a person meets Condition A and Condition B he/she will get the discount or if a person meets Condition C and must meet condition E she/he will get the discount as well.

I tried the following formula but is not working:

```
=IF(AND(AND(OR(A11="Cta Corriente"),B11>25),A11="Cta Cte",B11>23),"Discount","No discount")
```

I'm getting `No discount` in all cases:

([image: SO30656179 question example]

Comment: Is not E is D Im sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
=IF(OR(AND(A11="Cta Cte",B11>23),AND(A11="Cta Corriente",B11>25)),"discount","no discount")
```

[image]

Comment: It Works amazing!! :) I did not know that I was able to use AND after a comma and also with your formula I understood that there were  2 AND conditions and I see that starting with (OR( was part of the solution . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=IF(OR(AND(A11="Cta Corriente",B11>25),AND(A11="Cta Cte",B11>23)),"Discount","No discount")
```

What you were saying was `((OR C) AND D) AND A AND B`. A little off what you were looking for :)

If future, construct them step by step. My thought process was as follows.

Ok we want the conditions: `AND(A,B)` and `AND(C,D)`, we also know with want either of them so we wrap them in an `OR`.

That leaves us with `OR(AND(A,B), AND(C,D))`.

Im not very good at explaining these things but I hope that helps.

Comment: It gave me an error : (  but yes one is AND and the other is OR and AND

Comment: No problem I tried with that one but all of them are giving me no discount so I tried with the one that Teylyn gave me . Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

A little shorter (OR, if having trouble with these functions, don't use them!):

```
=IF((A11="Cta Cte")*(B11>23)+(A11="Cta Corriente")*(B11>25),"Discount","No discount")
```

The easiest way to see what this is doing may be to create a few examples and then apply Evaluate Formula to them.

Comment: Wow that one works fine same as the one Teylyn gave me . What means the "*" and the "+"  ???

Comment: It's AND and OR in geek speak. :-)))) `*` acts like AND. `+` acts like OR. More detailed explanation will take a few pages.

Comment: :O I will read about it . Is good to learn something new :) Thank You Teylyn